# How to write on route to receive request from external laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

```
$client = new Client();
$response = 
$client->GET('http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/eDeskApi/module/SOMEFUNCTION',
[
 'json' => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

This is how i'm sending a request to external LARAVEL api.
I just want to know what do i need to write in laravel api router to get something return when i send this request.
Currently i have the following code on laravel api router

```
Route::GET('module/url', 'Nameof Controller@NameOfMethhod');
```

And in controller looks like:

```
public function GetApplicationModuleList()
{
  echo 'something';
  //i want to print the parameter value which i just sent by above mention request.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your request from `GET` to `POST` if you want to send some request body there.

Also your function should take an argument of:

`Illuminate\Http\Request` type.

After that you can access you request body by doing:

`$request -> all();`

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But if i change it to POST its showing `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: can you provide code snippet that you have for this?

Comment: Thanx for you approach.. Solved this.. :)